# How to apply xmodem CRC on generating and checking

Tags: python, crc, crc16, xmodem

I've iterated of lots of articles - for some reason I couldn't find any which describes what must be a simple procedure: How to combine a calculated CRC with the original message, so that calculating CRC again results in 0 (=checks out as correct)? I did find several examples with 'longhand' calculations (only 2 or 3 bit CRCs), but no example which uses a library function such as `[crcmod][1]` (Python library).

Here's a simple program I wrote to check it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

import crcmod

def test_cycle():
    test_str = b"123456789"
    orig_msg = test_str
    print("Original message: {:s}".format(orig_msg.hex()))

    #~ crc_calc = crcmod.predefined.Crc('xmodem')
    crc_calc = crcmod.Crc(
                0x11021,
                rev = False,
                initCrc = 0x0000,
                xorOut = 0x0000)

    crc_calc.update(orig_msg)
    print("CRC: {:04x}".format(crc_calc.crcValue))

    lo = crc_calc.crcValue & 0xff
    hi = crc_calc.crcValue >> 8
    new_msg = test_str + bytes((hi, lo))
    print("Crc appended: {:s}".format(new_msg.hex()))

    crc_calc.update(new_msg)
    print("CRC: {:04x}".format(crc_calc.crcValue))


def main(args):
    test_cycle()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

There are some commented lines, from experiments with different byte ordering. The results from the program are:

```
Original message: 313233343536373839
CRC: 31c3
Crc appended: 31323334353637383931c3
CRC: 00ef
```

The first CRC (`31C3`) seems to check out with correspond with [the expected values for xmodem-CRC](http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/crcmod.predefined.html#id3). I tried, in many ways, to combine the obtained CRC with the original string, but never obtain '0'. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't know your Python module but my own Pascal library gives a CRC 0 for
`31323334353637383931C3`, verified by https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html.

Comment: @gammatester - the confusion was on my side. I didn't expect the CRC class' method `update` to append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crc_calc.update(new_msg)` adds the entire content of `new_msg` to the CRC. Since `crc_calc` already holds the result of `313233343536373839`, you are effectively calculating the CRC of `31323334353637383931323334353637383931c3` and this is indeed `00ef`.

To add only the two bytes to the calculation, use

```
crc_calc.update(bytes((hi, lo)))
```

Alternatively, use a new instance of `crcmod.Crc()`, or reset the `crcValue` of the existing instance before doing a new calculation

```
crc_calc.crcValue = 0
crc_calc.update(new_msg)
```

Both will give you a result of 0

Answer (score 2):

Some background for those arriving at this question, wondering about appending CRCs.

If a CRC is *properly* appended to the message that it is the CRC of, and there are no errors introduced in the message or CRC, the the CRC of that whole thing will be a *constant* dependent only on the definition of that CRC.

To *properly* append the CRC requires care in the bit ordering. For the generic CRC definition afforded by `crcmod`, if `rev` is false, then the bits must be appended *most* significant first. If `rev` is true, then the bits must be appended *least* significant first. For byte-oriented messages, this means first off that the width of the CRC has to be a multiple of eight bits (which by the way is all that `crcmod` permits), and that the CRC be appended in big-endian order or little-endian order respectively.

The resulting *constant* is not always zero, depending on the definition of the CRC. It *is* zero if the `xorOut` value for the CRC is zero. Otherwise the constant is the CRC of *n* zero bits, where *n* is the width of the CRC, and where the initial CRC value provided is zero (*not* `initCrc`). As an example, for the standard CRC-32, the CRC-32 of a message with its CRC-32 appended in little-endian order is always `0x2144df1c`.

For this particular question, the CRC is appended in big-endian order, so `31 c3`, and CRC of the resulting message + CRC is then zero.

Comment: The explanation is that the bit holding the _coefficient of the highest exponent_ must always come first. When `rev` is False, the polynomials are represented using the bit whose integer value is 2^0 for the coefficient of X^0 and the coefficient of X^(n-1) goes into the bit 2^(n-1). So, the byte containing that bit comes first. When `rev` is True, the bit 2^(n-1) is used for the coefficient of X^0 and the coefficient of X^(n-1) goes into the bit 2^0. So, in that case, LSB comes first. See [What is the correct byte order for transmitting the computed CRC](https://aweiler.com/crc/crcnaq.html).